# Colors of options page in VSIX are not persisted

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vsix

I have made a Visual Studio Extension (VSIX) (see: [Pretty Doc Comments - Visual Studio Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=OlivierJacot-Descombes.PrettyDocComments)).

It has an options page looking like this:

[image]

It is created automatically by a [`DialogPage`](https://github.com/OJacot-Descombes/PrettyDocComments/tree/master/PrettyDocComments/CustomOptions) looking like this:

```cs
public class OptionPageGrid : DialogPage
{
    [Category("Sizing")]
    [DisplayName("Font scaling")]
    [Description("By how much the editor font size is multiplied to get the comment base font size (default is 0.8).")]
    [DefaultValue(0.8)]
    public double FontScaling { get; set; } = 0.8;

    [Category("Sizing")]
    [DisplayName("Comment width in columns")]
    [Description("Width of the rendered doc comment in columns (default is 80).")]
    [DefaultValue(80)]
    public int CommentWidthInColumns { get; set; } = 80;

    [Category("Shape Colors")]
    [DisplayName("Comment background color")]
    [Description("Background color of rendred comments (default is LightGoldenrodYellow).")]
    [TypeConverter(typeof(System.Drawing.ColorConverter))]
    public System.Drawing.Color CommentBackColor { get; set; } = System.Drawing.Color.LightGoldenrodYellow;

    [Category("Shape Colors")]
    [DisplayName("Comment line color")]
    [Description("Color of comment frame and separator lines (default is DarkKhaki).")]
    [TypeConverter(typeof(System.Drawing.ColorConverter))]
    public System.Drawing.Color CommentLineColor { get; set; } = System.Drawing.Color.DarkKhaki;

    [Category("Shape Colors")]
    [DisplayName("Code block background color")]
    [Description("Background color of <code>blocks</code> (default is Gainsboro).")]
    [TypeConverter(typeof(System.Drawing.ColorConverter))]
    public System.Drawing.Color CodeBlockBackColor { get; set; } = System.Drawing.Color.Gainsboro;

    [Category("Text Colors")]
    [DisplayName("Text color")]
    [Description("Color of normal text (default is Black).")]
    [TypeConverter(typeof(System.Drawing.ColorConverter))]
    public System.Drawing.Color TextColor { get; set; } = System.Drawing.Color.Black;

    [Category("Text Colors")]
    [DisplayName("Special text color")]
    [Description("Color of special text, e.g. links and references (default is DarkSlateBlue).")]
    [TypeConverter(typeof(System.Drawing.ColorConverter))]
    public System.Drawing.Color SpecialTextColor { get; set; } = System.Drawing.Color.DarkSlateBlue;

    [Category("Text Colors")]
    [DisplayName("HTML comment text color")]
    [Description("Color of HTML <!-- comment --> text (default is ForestGreen).")]
    [TypeConverter(typeof(System.Drawing.ColorConverter))]
    public System.Drawing.Color HtmlCommentTextColor { get; set; } = System.Drawing.Color.ForestGreen;

    [Category("Text Colors")]
    [DisplayName("Error text and frame color")]
    [Description("Color used to display XML parsing errors (default is Red).")]
    [TypeConverter(typeof(System.Drawing.ColorConverter))]
    public System.Drawing.Color ErrorTextColor { get; set; } = System.Drawing.Color.Red;

    public override void SaveSettingsToStorage()
    {
        base.SaveSettingsToStorage();
        Options.Refresh();
    }
}
```

This page is registered like this:

```cs
[PackageRegistration(UseManagedResourcesOnly = true, AllowsBackgroundLoading = true)]
[Guid(PrettyDocCommentsPackage.PackageGuidString)]
[ProvideOptionPage(typeof(OptionPageGrid), "Pretty Doc Comments", "General",  0, 0, true)]
public sealed class PrettyDocCommentsPackage : AsyncPackage { ... }
```

E.g. the option "Comment width in columns" (`int`) is persisted, but the color properties are not despite the fact that I specified a `[TypeConverter(typeof(System.Drawing.ColorConverter))]` for them.

Why are the colors not persisted and what can I do to fix it?

Note: I prefer not to store the colors in "Fonts and Colors" as they are harder to find there and I prefer to have all the options in one place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea what the exact problem was, but implementing [Mads Kristensen's Options example](https://github.com/madskristensen/OptionsSample) solved the problem. Definitely a better solution than the one shown in the original documentation [Create an options page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/creating-an-options-page?view=vs-2022).

Comment: The base classes in that sample use the ShellSettingsManager to persist the various properties. If you set breakpoints in Load/LoadAsync, and Save/SaveAsync methods in that https://github.com/madskristensen/OptionsSample/blob/master/src/Options/BaseOptionModel.cs

And debug the sample, you can see exactly how/when they are invoked.